# How to make Dock always visible in full screen mode

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, fullscreen

I use Virtualbox to run ubuntu 18.04 and I use Virtualbox's seamless-mode. The functionality of seamless mode is broken and the dock and menu-bars clipped out.

The only way I found to get things working nice is to use fullscreen mode in Ubuntu. When I press the *Windows Key* , Ubuntu will show the dock and the open applications.

I'm looking for a way to force the Dock to always show, specifically in fullscreen mode. I downloaded `dconf-tools` by running `sudo apt install dconf-tools` but the autohide in fullscreen and autohide options don't effect the dock when in fullscreen.

How can I make the dock always visible when in fullscreen mode?